# How do I alert the latitude in this Google Maps javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, api, google-maps

As you can see, there is a line in there that does an alert. It's "`undefined`".  Whereas if I just alert `results[0].geometry.location`, it alerts `(41.321, 41.556)`.

I just want to alert it and set it (as an int) to one of my id_lat and id_longs...

```
$("#geocodesubmit").click(function(){
        $("#id_lat").val("");
        $("#id_long").val("");
        var address = $("#addressinput").val();
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            $("#badlocation_holder").hide();
            $("#map_canvas").show();
            $("#map_canvas_holder").show().css("background-color", "#E6E6FA").animate({"background-color":"#f5f5f5"}, 800);
            ;
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);  
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

            alert(results[0].geometry.location[1]); //this is undefined.

            $("#id_lat").val(results[0].geometry.location[0]);
            $("#id_long").val(results[0].geometry.location[1]);


            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map, 
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                draggable:true
            });
          } else {
              $("#map_canvas_holder").hide();
              $("#badlocation_holder").show().css("background-color","#F08080").animate(
              {"background-color":"#f5f5f5"},800);
          }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use `results[0].geometry.location.lat()` to get the latitude and `results[0].geometry.location.lng()` for the longitude.

Answer (score 6):

[If you look at the API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#GeocodingResults), `location` isn't an array (that's the main issue here), it's a property, so `.location` is the correct way to access it, not `.location[0]`.

The official documentation is a bit hard to find for specific types, [but here are updated docs on that `location` (a `LatLng` type)](http://google-maps-api-version-3.touraineverte.com/en/code/apis/maps/version/v/3/documentation/reference/LatLng/LatLng.htm):

The `toString()` is what you're getting in an alert `(lat, long)`, there's also `.lat()` for latitude and `.lng()` for longitude, like this:

```
alert(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
alert(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
```